# Copy .aspx file with code behind programmatically

Tags: asp.net, file, webforms, copy, code-behind

How do I programmatically copy `.aspx` page with its code behind?

I know how to use *File.Copy* method, but it is not what I need.
I'm doing help system. In this help system now just two types (*Situation1*, *Situation2*). I have to make some function to create *Situation3*, *Situation4*, so on.

I can use some class with types like *Situation1*, *Situation2*, so on. But problem is that I need different URL's for all pages. I can't just do something like `Help.aspx?type=situation1, help.aspx?type=situation2`.

It should be like `Situation1.aspx, Situation2.aspx, Situation3.aspx`. May somebody give examples on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea you are proceeding down is a bad one. Here's a few reasons:

- How are you going to get the new page into source code control (which you *should* be using)?
- What if you need to make a change that affects all the SituationX.aspx files? You have to go to every file and fix them individually.
- It can also be a security vulnerability if a user is able to affect the content of the file in any way.

A better solution is to use *routing*. The URL a user requests doesn't necessarily have to map to a particular file. This gives the developer more control over how their URL's look, creating ["hackable"](https://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/990/) URL's that also look great for search engine optimization. It's also a lot easier to tell someone to go to, and removes the file extension from the URL (which the user doesn't need to know or care about).

Add this to your global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs)

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Situation/{situationId}", "~/Situation.aspx");
}
```

Have a single Web form called Situation.aspx. It can then inspect the URL to retrieve the ID of the situation page that the user requests. And it can retrieve data from your database about that particular situation:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        var id = Page.RouteData.Values["situationId"];
        var situation = Database.GetSituationById(id);
        ShowSituationOnPage(situation);
    }   
}
```

The user then accesses `example.com/Situations/1` and the page can retrieve the correct situation and display it for them.

See [How to Define Routes For Web Forms Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx) and [How to Access URL Parameters on a routed page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535620.aspx), both on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice, it will help me, but not in this situation... I'm doing for one client, so you might know about clients request ))). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Khazratbek It doesn't matter if it's for a client or not. If they told you how they want it implemented, then go explain to them how this is better. If they didn't tell you how to implement it, then just do it. This is the correct way.